# iOS Swift: run screen recording programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, recording, replaykit

Is it possible to start screen recording (through Control Center) without user prompt?

I mean to ask user permission for the first time and after that to start and stop recording programmatically only?

I need to record screen only for specific events.

Comment: You can try applescript for this. Does following script help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63056/can-applescript-be-used-to-automate-a-screen-recording-session-on-os-x

Comment: I speak about iPhone. Does AppleScript work in iPhones?

Comment: Aah.. my bad. For iOS did you try ReplayKit?

Comment: Yes, of course. I use it for broadcasting, but my question is how to start screen recording from code.